# How to find the proof method chosen by the "proof" command

Tags: isabelle

Take the statement `P ⟹ Q ⟹ P ∧ Q` as an example. You may prove it with:

```
lemma dummy: "P ⟹ Q ⟹ P ∧ Q" 
proof
  assume "P" "Q"
  show "P" by fact
  show "Q" by fact
qed
```

Here the `proof` command chooses some proof method, which generates two subtasks, a proof of `P`, followed by a proof of `Q`.

Is there a way for me to find out which method was chosen by `proof`?

---

*Note: I know the proof method chosen here was `rule conjI`, my question is for the general case.*

Comment: The proof method is always the same: `standard`. I'm not sure how to see which rule it applied, though.

Comment: As @NieDzejkob already mentioned, the proof method chosen by `proof` is `standard`. I'm not an expert in Isabelle/ML, but the following ML snippet traverses the proof term and prints the list of used theorems, which may be helpful:

    ML_command ‹

      val thm = @{thm dummy};

      val body = Proofterm.strip_thm_body (Thm.proof_body_of thm);


      val all_thms =

        Proofterm.fold_body_thms

          (fn {name, ...} => insert (op =) name) [body] [];


      writeln (commas_quote all_thms);
    ›

Comment: @JavierDíaz This is quite impressive. The only problem I see is that it can't easily show the proof method when the `proof` command is nested inside another `proof`. Nonetheless, I think it's still worthy of being posted as an answer.

Comment: @LuizMartins Already posted as an answer.

Comment: Just a quick addition: `standard` isn't necessarily just the application of a single rule; if I recall correctly, it can also do an `unfold_locales` when you're proving a locale assumption, or an `intro_classes` for class instances. These may involve more complex unfolding and application of facts in the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @NieDzejkob already mentioned, the proof method chosen by `proof` is `standard`. I'm not an expert in Isabelle/ML, but the following ML snippet traverses the proof term and prints the list of used theorems, which may be helpful in trying to find out the specific theorem used by `standard`:

```
ML_command ‹
  val thm = @{thm dummy};
  val body = Proofterm.strip_thm_body (Thm.proof_body_of thm);
  val all_thms = Proofterm.fold_body_thms (fn {name, ...} => insert (op =) name) [body] [];
  writeln (commas_quote all_thms);
›
```